# How to compare the value of two lists is the same and match the Elements?

Tags: python, string

I have two list of list values

first value is

```
first = [['Admin', 'access','30','pass'],['Admin', 'access','32','yes'],['sam', 'ok','10'],['client', 'access', '50']]
```

second value is

```
second = [['test.com.Admin', 'access','30'],['john', 'ok', '70'],['robert\\client', 'access', '40']]
```

how to compare the value of the first list entry [0] is the same as the second list [0] but the value of the second list is some string and symbol is  there

so how to match the value of my first list with my second list if it matches then print the result like this

if the value is like this ['Admin', 'access','30'],['Admin', 'access','32'] its get only one value because some element is different. 31.32 does not match,

example: so if [0] matches, the entire first value is retrieved, even the other item doesn't match

output result:

```
['Admin', 'access','30','pass']
['Admin', 'access','32','yes']
['client', 'access', '50']
```

so i need to omit some substrings and symbols

if my first list[0] matches this second list[0] for any name

Is it possible to use regular expression matching?

code: (but it does not get correctly)

```
import re
first = [['Admin', 'access','30','pass'],['Admin', 'access','32','yes'],['sam', 'ok','10'],['client', 'access', '50']]
second = [['test.com.Admin', 'access','30'],['john', 'ok', '70'],['robert\\client', 'access', '40']]

def filter_elements(first, second):
    return [f for f in first if any(re.search(f[0], s[0]) for s in second)]

filter_elements(first, second)
```

Comment: Why is `['sam', 'ok','10']` in the output? What does it match?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what constitutes a matching pair of elements. What logic do I use to say this element in `first` matches that element ni `second`

Comment: @SargeATM i need to match first list[0] EX: 'Admin' and second list[0] only, if match i print first list , (first value based on the name)

Comment: Does `Admin` and `test.com.Admin` match because they both end with the `Admin` "symbol"?

Comment: @SargeATM yes and will print the matching name with all values ['Admin', 'access','30','pass'] ['Admin', 'access','32','yes']

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use `zip` and `endswith` since the matches are always at the same position and the matching portion of the username is always at the end of the string in the second list:

```
>>> first = [['Admin', 'access'],['sam', 'ok'],['client', 'access'],['sam', 'failed']]
>>> second = [['test.com.Admin', 'access'],['john', 'ok'],['robert\\client', 'access'],['cab.com//sam', 'failed']]
>>> for f, s in zip(first, second):
...     if s[0].endswith(f[0]):
...         print(f)
...
['Admin', 'access']
['client', 'access']
['sam', 'failed']
```

Comment: if I change the second value as the first and the first value as the second, how can I match the second value based on the name?

Comment: if you change the second value as the first and the first value as the second then all you need to do is match the first value based on the name instead of matching the second value based on the name

Comment: but if the first value has an extra element, it doesn't print the results and get an empty

Answer (score 0):

## Use symbols and whitelist filter

First define a symbol, and then create a whitelist

##### SYMBOL DEFINITION

I'm going to use the definition of a python identifier (limited to ASCII) at the end of a string.

```
symbol_rexp = re.compile("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$")
```

##### WHITELIST SYMBOLS

Use the `second` list to create a whitelist of symbols. If the `first` list matches the whitelist, it passes through to the results.

```
second_keys = [e[0] for e in second]
whitelist = [m.group(0) for m in map(symbol_rexp.search, second_keys) if m]
```

##### WHITELIST FILTER

Use `symbol_rexp` to match symbols in `first` to `whitelist`

```
first_keys = [e[0] for e in first]
result_index = [i for (i, m) in enumerate(map(symbol_rexp.search, first_keys)) if m if m.group(0) in whitelist]
result = [first[i] for i in result_index]
```

##### FINAL SOLUTION

The tested final solution:

```
import re

first = [['Admin', 'access','30','pass'],['Admin', 'access','32','yes'],['sam', 'ok','10'],['client', 'access', '50']]
second = [['test.com.Admin', 'access','30'],['john', 'ok', '70'],['robert\\client', 'access', '40']]

symbol_rexp = re.compile("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$")
second_keys = [e[0] for e in second]
whitelist = [m.group(0) for m in map(symbol_rexp.search, second_keys) if m]
first_keys = [e[0] for e in first]
result_index = [i for (i, m) in enumerate(map(symbol_rexp.search, first_keys)) if m if m.group(0) in whitelist]
result = [first[i] for i in result_index]

print(result)
```

Comment: but if the first value has an extra element, it doesn't print the results and get an empty first = [['Admin', 'access','30','ok'],['Admin', 'access','32','pass'],['sam', 'ok','10'],['client', 'access', '50']]